# No data in CSV : Error uploading CSV

Tags: excel, csv

While trying to upload a CSV file, I am getting this error message "No data in CSV".

I remember it worked once (the field only takes CSV files) and now when I tried to save my excel as CSV (comma delimited) and upload, I'm getting this message.

It's strange, since the file is NOT empty. So the problem is coming from elsewhere.

**Solved**

The problem was that, excel was saving the CSV not with comma but with semi colon, this I found after opening the CSV in notepad. And I was choosing comma as separator while uploading the file in the backend.

Comment: Upload? Where? What application? You will need to provide a few more details.

Comment: Richard, uploading to the backend of a custom built website. But I thought the problem is coming from the way the excel is getting saved - or something on that level.

Comment: This is probably too localized to be useful to others... Try comparing a csv that works with one that does not and see if you can figure out what the critical differnence is between the two. Otherwise contact whoever administers your custom website, and see if you can get some clarification about requirements for the CSVs, since apparently they must be CSVs with a particular format.

Comment: Solved. The problem was that, excel was saving the CSV not with comma but with semi colon, this I found after opening the CSV in notepad. And I was choosing comma as separator while uploading the file in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

THis may be a shot int he dark, But Excel 2010 lets you save spreadsheets in three .csv formats.
Regular .csv
Mac .csv
and ms-dos .csv

Try each of those to see if they work with your upload process.

Otherwise I'd second @Daniel Cook's comment to contact the developer of the back-end website for additional troubleshooting. It's likely that it's their system is behaving unexpected, not your CSV file.

Comment: Thanks Gimp, tried all three CSV formats. The reason why I thought this might be something linked to the excel file is that it worked once earlier. I'll try to see with the backend coders.

Comment: K i'll delete my answer then after lunch. Good luck.